# How to replace null values with a text?

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I need to display Employee `last_name` and their commission amount from employees table in Oracle SQL, but the condition is if it encounter `NULL` value I need to print *"No Commission"*.
For the first part I wrote:

```
select last_name, commission_pct from employees;
```

But I am unable to get how to replace `NULL` values with *"No Commission"*.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `case` expression:

```
select last_name
     , case when commision_pct is null then 'No Commission' else commision_pct end    
from employees;
```

or `coalesce`:

```
select last_name
     , coalesce(commision_pct, 'No Commission')
from employees;
```

or `nvl`:

```
 select last_name
     , nvl(commision_pct, 'No Commission')
from employees;
```

*P.S. In case `commision_pct`'s datatype is not `varchar` you should also use `cast` or `to_char`.*

Comment: Returns Error: Inconsistent datatype: Expected CHAR got NUMBER

Comment: `commision_pct` should be stored as `varchar` in the table otherwise you need to use `CAST`

Comment: Okay yes commission_pct is stored as NUMBER.

Comment: `nvl(to_char(commision_pct), 'No Commission')`

Comment: @user308967: You are welcome. And kudos to _ughai_.)

Comment: `nvl(commision_pct, 'No Commission') as commision_pct` is my choice.

Answer (score 8):

For Oracle

```
select last_name, nvl(commission_pct,'No Commission')
from employees;
```

For SQL

```
select last_name, isnull(commission_pct,"No Commission") as commission_pct
    from employees;
```

Answer (score 4):

It is as simple as you can see, **Isnull()** Used to Replace NULL values to the default value we pass there, so what i did here is If **"commission_pct"** having NULL value then it'll replace that with **"No Commission"** text, which i have passed in ISNULL() as 2nd parameter.

```
  select last_name, 
    ISNULL(commission_pct,'No Commission') AS commission_pct
    from employees;
```

Comment: Avoid code only answers. Add some description about your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative, quite simple and precise:

```
nvl(to_char(commision_pct), 'No Commission')
```

Since, `commision_pct` is **NUMBER** data type, `to_char` will explicitly convert it into string.

Answer (score 2):

select Last_Name, 
decode(nvl(salary*commission_pct,'0'),0,'No Commission',salary*commission_pct) as COMM
from employees;

Answer (score 0):

how if the condition like this:

```
Select job_id, job_title, employee_id
from jobs join job_history using (job_id);
```

and show all of the employee_id who has been working in there, if is it not, replacing into `varchar`