# Function which prints the input if the row value is NULL in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have a Table named CustomerDetails:

DeletKey | ReplacedKey

CID0001    | CUSTID01

CID0002    | CUSTID02

CID0003    | (NULL)

When the input given to function is CID0001, CID0003

The output should be CUSTID01, CID0003.

As the CID0001 is replaced with CUSTID01 and CID0003 is null, it should return the input value.

How to write a function in plsql with number of input values. When the input Customer ID is deleted and replaced, it should return the replaced Customer ID.
If it is not replaced (ReplacedKey is NULL) it should print the input value.

My code: without input. How should I add input value to this?

```
create or replace function ChangeList
as
cursor c1
select replaced ReplacedKey.CustomerDetails%type
deleted DeletKey.CustomerDetails%type
from CustomerDetails;
begin
  open c1;
   loop ``
     if ReplacedKey is null
     then
     dbms_output.put_line('DeletedKey' ||deleted);
     else
     dbms_output.put_line('ReplacedKey'||replaced);
     end if;
   end loop;
 close c1:
end;
```

Input of the prg- Nothing

Output of the prg- DelettedKey CID0003
        ReplacedKey CUSTID01

The input I should give: CID0001
                         CID0003

The output I need      : CUSTID01
                         CID0003

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: @eviltech Actually I wrote a function with a cursor but its not working out.

Comment: Another problem which I have is there is no one input. As I'm giving number of inputs. I dont know how to give the input to the function!

Comment: Sorry if this question is silly. I'm beginner in plsql

Comment: Look up the functions `COALESCE`, `NVL`, `NVL2`, theyshould be helpful in solving your task.

Comment: The question isn't silly.  Your presentation needs some work.   What have you tried?   show us the code.   Show the inputs, and expected outputs.  Then as the question you are trying to get an answer too.  We aren't all mind readers.  Well most of us arn't, but now I go being silly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace null values with a text during display in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982375/how-to-replace-null-values-with-a-text-during-display-in-sql)

Comment: @diziaq Thank u for the suggestion. But instead of 'No commission' How to print the input which I give to the function?

Comment: You don't need to write such a function. It's already there: `coalesce()`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions030.htm#SQLRF00617

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a nvl fucntion

```
select NVL(ReplacedKey,DELETKEY) from table
```

Comment: create or replace function changelist (x varchar2)

Answer (score 0):

A function with parameter:

```
create or replace function ChangeList(p_cid varchar2) return varchar2
as
  ret varchar2;
begin 
  select nvl(ReplacedKey, p_cid) 
  into ret
  from CustomerDetails
  where DeletKey = p_cid;

  return ret;
exception when no_data_found then return 'no data found';
end;
```